# How to get rid of this infinite loop using useEffect and useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback, react-usecallback

I wanna load the first batch of comments immediately (using `useEffect`) and then load additional pages when a "load more" button is pressed.

The problem is that my current setup causes an infinite loop (caused by the dependency on `comments`).

If I remove the `fetchNextCommentsPage` function from the `useEffect` dependency list, everything seems to work, but **EsLint** complains about the missing dependency.

```
    const [comments, setComments] = useState<CommentModel[]>([]);
    const [commentsLoading, setCommentsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [commentsLoadingError, setCommentsLoadingError] = useState(false);

    const [paginationEnd, setPaginationEnd] = useState(false);

    const fetchNextCommentsPage = useCallback(async function () {
        try {
            setCommentsLoading(true);
            setCommentsLoadingError(false);
            const continueAfterId = comments[comments.length - 1]?._id;
            const response = await BlogApi.getCommentsForBlogPost(blogPostId, continueAfterId);
            setComments([...comments, ...response.comments]);
            setPaginationEnd(response.paginationEnd);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            setCommentsLoadingError(true);
        } finally {
            setCommentsLoading(false);
        }
    }, [blogPostId, comments])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNextCommentsPage();
    }, [fetchNextCommentsPage]);
```

Comment: have you tried not wrapping up the fetcher in useCallback?.

Comment: @aleEspinosaM Yes, that's what I started out with. Then EsLint lights up the whole function and warns that this will cause the useEffect to run on every render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Đào-minh-hạt for their answer. I improved it by passing the `continueAfterId` as an argument, rather than holding it in another state (which, I think, is more intuitive):

```
const [comments, setComments] = useState<CommentModel[]>([]);
const [commentsLoading, setCommentsLoading] = useState(true);
const [commentsLoadingError, setCommentsLoadingError] = useState(false);

const [paginationEnd, setPaginationEnd] = useState(false);

const fetchNextCommentsPage = useCallback(async function (continueAfterId?: string) {
    try {
        setCommentsLoading(true);
        setCommentsLoadingError(false);
        const response = await BlogApi.getCommentsForBlogPost(blogPostId, continueAfterId);
        setComments(existingComments => [...existingComments, ...response.comments]);
        setPaginationEnd(response.paginationEnd);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setCommentsLoadingError(true);
    } finally {
        setCommentsLoading(false);
    }
}, [blogPostId]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchNextCommentsPage();
}, [fetchNextCommentsPage]);
```

And then in my load-more button's onClick:

```
<Button
   variant="outline-primary"
   onClick={() => fetchNextCommentsPage(comments[comments.length - 1]?._id)}>
    Load more comments
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Never put the state you want to mutate in the dependencies list as it will always raise an infinite loop issue.
The common way to solve this is to use the callback function of `setState` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate.

If you want your effect triggered only once, put something that never changes after the first loading.
When you want to load more when pressing a button, just change the dependencies of your effect to run your effect again with new dependency value.

```js
    const [comments, setComments] = useState<CommentModel[]>([]);
    const [commentsLoading, setCommentsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [commentsLoadingError, setCommentsLoadingError] = useState(false);
    const [continueAfterId, setContinueAfterId] = useState(null)

    const [paginationEnd, setPaginationEnd] = useState(false);

    const fetchNextCommentsPage = useCallback(async function () {
        try {
            setCommentsLoading(true);
            setCommentsLoadingError(false);
            const response = await BlogApi.getCommentsForBlogPost(blogPostId, continueAfterId);
            setComments(previousState => [...previousState, ...response.comments]);
            setPaginationEnd(response.paginationEnd);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            setCommentsLoadingError(true);
        } finally {
            setCommentsLoading(false);
        }
    }, [blogPostId, continueAfterId]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNextCommentsPage();
    }, [fetchNextCommentsPage]);

    const onButtonPressed = useCallback(() => {
        // continueAfterId is one of the dependencies of fetchNextCommentsPage so it will change `fetchNextCommentsPage`, hence trigger the effect
        setContinueAfterId(comments[comments.length - 1]?._id)
    }, [comments])
```

Comment: Thank you! This trigger the initial load twice. Any idea why? Maybe this only happens in debugging because of React's double render. 
**Edit: I think the double fetch is caused by React's strict mode and should not happen in production.**

Comment: Also, what do you think about passing `continueAfterId` as an argument to `fetchNextCommentspage` and removing it from the dependency array of the useCallback? It feels more intuitive to me than using `continueAfterId` as a trigger.

Comment: @FlorianWalther yes, you can absolutely do that so onButtonPress you will calcuate the next id and call the fetchComments(newId) again. It's an even better solution actually :D. Then you don't need another state for it.

Comment: Do you want to edit your solution or should I post my approach myself?